# How do I get the full path for a file in finder?

Tags: finder

I look for a file in finder, finder finds it.  But, I'd like to find it's full path. How do I do that?

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be this complicated.  Apple loves to hide things from us so that we are more dependent on their gadgets.  For another example, see how difficult it is to actually see someone's phone **number** when you or they call.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can also enter the following in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool YES`
then
`killall Finder`

This will display the full path in the titlebar.

[image: path]

to turn it back off change the -bool `YES` to `NO`

Or if you want to copy the text of the path you can drag the file into Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the kind of thing that should be an option in the "Show View Options" dialog or finder preferences.

Comment: How can I copy the path?

Comment: This is so ridiculous...  Are you self aware ? "Apple, different to be different."

Answer (score 75):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>  <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>   while file is highlighted to copy its path to the macOS clipboard.

(option-command-c)

Easier than all of these by a long shot, IMO.

Comment: that's a nice extra to know, but you forgot to mention that this only copies it to the macos clipboard

Answer (score 20):

There are a few ways:

- Right-click the folder name in the top of the window

  [image: Finder Window Path]
- In the Finder choose "View > Show Path Bar"

  [image: Finder Path Bar]
- Use [Go2Shell](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go2shell/id445770608?mt=12) to open a terminal window at that location

Comment: I cannot see the View option, I have no menu bar.  Any help?

Comment: The menu bar I am referring to is at the top of the screen. It begins with the Apple icon, then Finder, File, Edit, View, Go, Window, and Help. If that menu bar is not visible you have much larger problems.

Comment: @DaveNelson, This doesn't show the real full Unix path though

Comment: This even works in 2023, 10 years later. Awesome :)

Answer (score 19):

Command-C on the file to copy, and Command-V on the command line in Terminal. Or drag the file to the Terminal window

Comment: I use drag all the time, didn't know pasting actually pasted the path in Terminal, thanks!

Comment: this only got me the file name, not the path.

Answer (score 9):

In Finder...

1. Select a file
2. Choose "View > Show Path Bar"
3. Right-click the Path Bar file name (or file icon)
4. Select "Copy as Pathname"
5. Paste the Pathname where you desire

[image: right click on the path bar file name]

Comment: just want to add that at least in recent versions of macOS (tried in Big Sur >11.6) there is a shortcut for this and is the nicest way to get the path: ⌥ ⌘ P

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on it and select "get info" and it should be written in the window that will pop the full path of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Install the FinderPath app

https://bahoom.com/finderpath/

It shows the full address when you click the title in Finder

Works just like Windows

Still works on MacOS 13.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and press info. Then you will get the file path infront of ***where***.

[More Info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N86Fcbk2Np0)

Comment: We are looking for answers which stand for their own and don't send people off-site for essential details. Also, did you read the other answers, especially https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/96742/9058?

Answer (score 0):

On Ventura 14, there's a menu option under **View** (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and then you see the entire path at the bottom of the window. Combine that with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to see hidden files and you're all set.  These settings persist after restart.

Note that the option under View does not appear (at least on my setup) unless you've first opened a Finder window.