# How do I get the location of a locked file in Preview?

Tags: finder, preview, path

I used to be able to Right-click or Command-click the name of the file in the title bar and see the path, whether the file was locked or not. Now when I open an attachment from Outlook (yes, I know it's in the Outlook temp folder - I just shouldn't have to manually navigate there), I can't actually open that folder from the Preview window.

When I try this method on an unlocked file, such as one on the Desktop, or in my Documents folder, it succeeds. So far, I can only see that the locked state is at issue.

I saw on another answer to a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96737/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-for-a-file-in-finder/96739#96739) they referred to ensuring View > Show Path Bar was selected - but that's not an option in my version of Preview.

Any ideas?

Additional info: I reviewed the updates I've recently installed, and I think the behavior changed after I installed the most recent Xcode update (v6.4) a few days ago (I doubt that iMovie, OneNote or HP Printer software updates were involved). On Yosemite 10.10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best way, but it works:

1. Open `Terminal.app`, type `dirname` (with space),
2. drug file into Terminal.app, and you'll see full escaped path of file (with `\` symbols if there're some spaces around).
3. Press `Enter` and this command prints full path without escapes, copy this output (with <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>)
4. with `Finder.app` type <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to open this directory.

**PS:** To drug file into Terminal you can drug this small icon on the window frame

Comment: Hmm - that does work! Though strangely, Preview always wants to interpret my drag on the small icon as a move of the Preview window the first time I do it - even when clicking squarely in the middle of that icon. Once I let go and try again, it does work. Like you said, not the best, but the only way I've found since the behavior changed. Thank you!